# Chrome dev tools exact computed value for CSS rules

Tags: css, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Is there anyway for instance I can get the exact pixel value (with decimal places) of a font to show in Chrome dev tools?

In **Firebug** (below) when I define a `%` value it shows the exact computed value in pixels up to 4 decimal places.

[image]

In **Chrome dev tools** (below) it only shows a whole number value.

[image]

In essence I want to be able to see in dev tools `► font-size: 13.7167px;`

Thanks!

Comment: really? does it make a difference?

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=254056

Comment: I can't see any difference in display on any browser. Font sizes are always rounded to the nearest pixel size on the screen, no matter how the size is specified (fractional px, pt, %). On both Linux and Windows.

Comment: And... right after I typed that, I found that when _printing_, there is a difference. Mozilla and IE do honour the fractional pixels, while Opera and Chromium don't. So, @Danko, yes it does! Look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/GSEx2/2/show/). Then look at the print preview.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you simply need to view `Computed Style` under Chrome Dev Tools.

```
Dev Tools -> Elements -> Computed Style
```

Comment: Please refer to my screenshot above, this is from computed styles. The problem is that it shows a whole number.

Answer (score 0):

In Chrome it may not give you the exact pixel value for one character, but it will give you the exact pixel size for the chunk of text if you look in computed under "width"